# pageBaseType in asp.net mvc3 razor - works! - no intellisense though?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I set a custom pageBaseType in web.config like this...

```
<pages pageBaseType="Status.Site.CustomWebViewPage">
```

In my cshtml view, I do this to make sure I see the CustomWebViewPage base type, I do.

```
Response.Write(this.GetType().FullName);
Response.Write(this.GetType().BaseType.FullName);
```

As a stupid test, my CustomWebViewPage has one method R that looks like this.

```
public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    public void R(string content)
    {
        Response.Write(content);
    }
}
```

And that works fine, I can call my silly R method from my cshtml and poof it works.

BUT - I am getting no intellisense love in the cshtml file, which is a major bummer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try closing and reopening the file. Also, does Razor IntelliSenses work for "regular" razor files?

Comment: +1 I almost hate when this works, because I've typically tried everything else at this point.